# Not able to Post using Open Graph with the token generated on Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to Post an Action on an Object using Open Graph. To test, I tried on Graph API Explorer where I generated the access_token using the required permission(publish_actionS). When I submit the API, I get an oAuth Error.

I saw the code for the Action in open graph Dashboard which had an access token. I used that access token and was able to post successfully. I dont know how that access_token is coming and how can I get that in my code to make sure the post works correctly.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured it out. Basically, I was not selecting the APP in the dropdown given on top left and hence it was trying to post using Graph API Explorer App which was wrong.